# Why didn't Lord Beckett order his ship to return fire in the end?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

In the end of *At World's End*, when *Flying Dutchman* came out of the sea to attack *HMS Endeavour*, Beckett started staring into blank. He not just delayed ordering his ship to fire, he completely ignored his subordinate's warnings. He continued to stare into blank while Black Pearl and Flying Dutchman inflicted damage to HMS Endeavour.

HMS Endeavour was flagship of East India Trading Company with way more cannons than that of Black Pearl and Flying Dutchman combined. It could definitely win even if Flying Dutchman couldn't be fully destroyed (remember that Black Pearl was able to damage Flying Dutchman using cannons).

Why didn't Lord Beckett order HMS Endeavour to attack?

Comment: Because he’d given up and an unkillable foe was now attacking them that had been on their side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [screenplay](https://thescriptsavant.com/pdf/Pirates_Of_The_Caribbean_At_Worlds_End.pdf) and [official novelisation](https://pirates.fandom.com/wiki/Pirates_of_the_Caribbean:_At_World%27s_End_(junior_novelization)) are in agreement that Beckett was basically paralysed by the realisation of his own failure and imminent demise. Interestingly, the scene is much shorter as *written*.

> "We need you, Jack," he said. "The Endeavour is very near." Beckett's ship was moving quickly toward them. Suddenly, the water began to move-and the Flying Dutchman came up again. She had new, white sails, and her men were clean and smart. Will Turner walked angrily onto the deck.
>
> The two ships sailed up on both sides of the Endeavour. **Beckett couldn't escape. "I can't destroy the pirates," he said to himself, "and now they will destroy me."**
>
> <sub><sup>World's End - Official Novelisation</sup></sub>

and

> ON THE ENDEAVOUR, as Beckett sails in for the kill
>
> **BECKETT:** *Nothing personal, Jack. It’s just good business.*
>
> SUDDENLY THE FLYING DUTCHMAN APPEARS, UP FROM THE DEPTHS, sailing alongside the Black Pearl. A clean slate grey, no longer encrusted —
>
> ON THE PEARL, Jack grins --
>
> **JACK:** *Full canvas!*
>
> **BARBOSSA:** *Aye full canvas!*
>
> ON THE FLYING DUTCHMAN, WILLIAM TURNER steps out on deck, a dark, avenging anger in his eyes, and now in control of the Flying Dutchman --
>   ON THE BLACK PEARL, Barbossa spins the wheel --
>   The Dutchman and the Black Pearl split, sail to either side of the Endeavour, trapping it in between.
>   ON THE ENDEAVOUR, Beckett stares in disbelief.
>   Groves, next to him, stares out and sees their doom. To Beckett —
>
> **GROVES:** *Orders, sir?*
>   (waits, nervous)
>   *Sir?*
>   (waits)
>   *Sir -- what do you commmand?*
>
> Beckett stares across — at Jack. States Jack Sparrow's question, to himself, with resignation, disgust, amazement:
>
> **BECKETT:** *Who am I?*
>
> Groves sees that Beckett has lost it — turns away.
>
> **GROVES:** *Abandon ship! All hands! Abandon ship!*